# Can I treat an `enum` variable as an `int` in C17?

Tags: c, types, enums, standards, c17

TL;DR: Is it right to assume, given `enum NAME {...};`, that `enum NAME n` is the same as `int n` during execution? Can `n` be operated on as if it were a `signed int`, even though it is declared as `enum NAME`? The reason: I really want to use `enum` types for return flags, as a type 'closed' with respect to bit-operations.

For example: Let `typedef enum FLAGS { F1 = 0x00000001, F2 = 0x00000002, F3 = 0x00000004 } FLAGS ;`
Then, `FLAGS f = F1 | F2;` assigns `3` to `f`, throwing no related errors or warnings. This and numerous other compiler-permitted usage scenarios, such as `f++`, makes me think I could legit treat `f` as if it were a `signed int`. Compiler used: MSVC'19, 16.9.1, with setting "C17 (2018) Standard (/std:c17)";

I searched the standard (the sketch [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2310.pdf)) and looked at other related questions, to find no mention of what suspect (and wished) to be a "silent promotion" of `enum NAME x` to `signed int x`, even though the identifiers have that type. This leads me to believe that the way `enum` behaves when assigned a value that isn't a member, is *implementation dependent*. I'm asking, in part, in order to confirm or deny this claim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C 2018 6.7.2.2 4 says:

> Each enumerated type shall be compatible with `char`, a signed integer type, or an unsigned integer type. The choice of type is implementation-defined, but shall be capable of representing the values of all the members of the enumeration…

So the answer to “Can I treat an `enum` variable as an `int` in C17?” is no, as an object with enumerated type might be effectively a `char` or other integer type different from `int`.

However, it is effectively an integer type, so `FLAGS f = F1 | F2;` will work: The `FLAGS` type must be capable of representing its values `F1` and `F2`, so whatever type is used for `FLAGS` must contain all the bits of `F1` and of `F2`, so it contains all the bits of `F1 | F2`.

Technically, you could construct a trap representation by manipulating bits, so it is not guaranteed that the type is closed under bit operations. For example, if a C implementation used two’s complement for 32-bit `int` but reserved the bit pattern `1000…0000` as a trap representation, then `INT_MIN & -2` would be a trap representation. (`INT_MIN` would have the bit pattern `1000…0001`, for 2<sup>31</sup>−1, and `-2` would have the pattern `1111…1110`.) This does not occur in C implementations without trap representations in its integer types.

We might question whether the fact that two types (an enumeration and its implementation-defined integer type) are compatible means we can use one as the other. Two types are compatible if they are the same (6.2.7 1), and the only things that can make types compatible but not the same involve qualifiers (like `const`) that are not an issue for this or involve other properties (such as array dimensions) that are not relevant to simple integer types.

Answer (score 0):

This is in chapter 6.4.4.3 of the PDF you linked:

> An identifier declared as an enumeration constant has type `int`.

Your thought of a promotion of `enum NAME x` to `signed int x` is not really true, as it is the **identifier** `NAME` that is of type `int`. The **value** `x` is of the type you use to define the identifier, and it is promoted to `int`.

Additionally, integer promotion takes place in integer operations.

**EDIT**

Some compilers are quite serious about the difference between `enum` and `int`, especially if they have an option to reduce the bit width to the smallest possible. For example, the one I'm using in a job's project, automatically inserts checks on *each* usage of an `enum` value against the defined values. Additionally, IIRC, it rejects all implicit conversions, we need to cast explicitly similarly to:

```
FLAGS f = (FLAGS)((int)F1 | (int)F2);
```

But this is an extension of this special beast called with specific safety options...